# VBA Transpose Table after n columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that looks like so:

```
+---------+------------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| country |    date    | proces | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 | val7 | val8 |
+---------+------------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| iso 1   | 11.03.2010 | over   |  111 |  222 |  222 |  333 |  444 |  555 |  666 |  777 |
| iso 2   | 11.03.2011 | over   |  111 |  222 |  222 |  333 |  444 |  555 |  666 |  777 |
+---------+------------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

And I would like to transform it to this:

```
+---------+------------+--------+-----+
| country |    date    | proces | val |
+---------+------------+--------+-----+
| iso 1   | 11.03.2010 | over   | 111 |
| iso 1   | 11.03.2010 | over   | 222 |
| iso 1   | 11.03.2010 | over   | 222 |
| iso 1   | 11.03.2010 | over   | 333 |
| iso 1   | 11.03.2010 | over   | 444 |
| iso 1   | 11.03.2010 | over   | 555 |
| iso 1   | 11.03.2010 | over   | 666 |
| iso 1   | 11.03.2010 | over   | 777 |
| iso 2   | 11.03.2011 | over   | 111 |
| iso 2   | 11.03.2011 | over   | 222 |
| iso 2   | 11.03.2011 | over   | 222 |
| iso 2   | 11.03.2011 | over   | 333 |
| iso 2   | 11.03.2011 | over   | 444 |
| iso 2   | 11.03.2011 | over   | 555 |
| iso 2   | 11.03.2011 | over   | 666 |
| iso 2   | 11.03.2011 | over   | 777 |
+---------+------------+--------+-----+
```

I have seen it can be done with the `Pivot Table Wizard` from Office'03. I am looking for a macro or someone explaining how one would be built. I am quite the rookie in the field, but currently learning how to build macros of my own. I tend to understand the code I am reading, I just have a hard time figuring out how to write on my own.

Comment: This is not consistent. The source table contains 8 values per country, date and process. The destination table contains 9 values per country, date and process. Please clarify.

Comment: I have changed the example to what it should. I want to transpose the whole table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tap `Alt+F11` and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to *Insert, Module*. Paste the following into the new pane titled something like Book1 - Module1 (Code).

```
Sub Transpose_ISO()
    Dim r As Long, lr As Long, rw As Long, c As Long, lc As Long, iBaseCols As Long
    iBaseCols = 3  'set to the number of semi-static column to repeat
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lc = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        rw = lr + 2
        .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, iBaseCols).Formula = "=""fld ""&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, COLUMN(A:A), 4, 1), 1, TEXT(,))"
        .Cells(rw, iBaseCols + 1) = "val"
        For r = 2 To lr
            For c = (iBaseCols + 1) To lc
                rw = rw + 1
                .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, iBaseCols) = .Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, iBaseCols).Value
                .Cells(rw, iBaseCols + 1) = .Cells(r, c).Value
            Next c
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

Tap `Alt+Q` to return to your worksheet then tap `ALt+F8` to open the Macros dialog and *Run* the macro.

Your results should be similar to the one in the image below. Note that the transposed results will be below the current data block.

[image]

Comment: You are the Bomb! :) I changed a few things as the number of columns is variable so I added lcol = Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column. Than you. I need to learn this type of data manipulation techniques. Do you know of a place to get me started on this?

Comment: @user2795105 - Thanks for the kind words. I've adjusted the code to be more dynamic in terms of the semi-static columns to repeat and the number of value columns on the right. There are hundreds if not thousands of examples of data matrix reorganizing on this site alone. Determining the data extents and basic looping are two methods that you will find common in a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that...

```
Sub Make()
    e = 2
    While Range("A" & e).Value <> ""
        If Range("E" & e).Value <> "" Then
            For i = 8 To 1 Step -1
                Range(e + 1 & ":" & e + 1).Insert xlShiftDown
                Range("A" & e + 1).Value = Range("A" & e).Value
                Range("B" & e + 1).Value = Range("B" & e).Value
                Range("C" & e + 1).Value = Range("C" & e).Value
                Range("D" & e + 1).Value = Cells(3 + i).Value
            Next
            Range(e & ":" & e).Delete
        End If
        e = e + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```